# Projects with using DomainModel or AnemicModel patterns

Tags: .net, hibernate, nhibernate, entity-framework

I'm a new in designing. 
I wanna to see real project's examples with applying either DomainModel or AnemicModel or maybe TransactionScript. 
could somebody give me links to source codes such projects?
or may be links to sites where it is showed in examples.
It is desireable using EF, L2SQL or NHiberniate in these projects.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Use this http://code.google.com/p/genericrepository/ will help you to create genric repository layer using EF, L2SQL, Nhibernate

http://code.google.com/p/sharp-architecture/ will guide you over DDD and best practices of Nhibernate